# Database for streets world wide?

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, geocoding

I use the downloadable [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) database for all countries, states, counties and cities in the world, but I wonder if there is a database for streets?

So you could pick: country -> state/department/district -> (county/region) -> city -> street in whatever country you like.

Because when I do a search for a street in Google Maps I can see all the upper levels (country/region/city). Is there a database you could download for MySQL for this?

There has to be a database for this, cause there are always national companies that provide this kind of information. Where did they get it from?

Comment: They pay lots of money to companies like Navteq.

Comment: are you sure? doesnt each country's government have a map/database for all places/streets? sounds weird if they dont. the question is, how could i get it? just call someone in the government and ask for it? shouldn´t this kind of information be free to use? or is it commercial?

Comment: It costs lots of money to generate an accurate database of all streets in a country.  Why should it be made available for free?

Comment: why would geonames make it available then? but for locations and not addresses? free is good!

Comment: I have no idea.  Ask them, not me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked out [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)? It is free and has a export screen that lets you download the data in XML and other formats.

Those concerned with the accruacy of the OpenStreetMap data may want to read what [ITO](http://www.itoworld.com/static/about) has to say about [OpenStreetMap's data for Haiti](http://itoworld.blogspot.com/2010/02/ito-world-at-ted-2010-project-haiti.html).

> Enter OpenStreetMap, the wiki map of the world, CrisisMappers and an impromptu community of volunteers who collaborated to produce the most authoritative map of Haiti in existence.

If you have 5 minutes you may want to watch this [TED video](http://www.ted.com/talks/tim_berners_lee_the_year_open_data_went_worldwide.html) by Tim Berners-Lee talking about what is being done with OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: But it's not necessarily reliable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but i would like to have a world wide database i could download and import to mysql like the one for geonames.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Navteq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navteq) or [Tele Atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele_Atlas).
They will charge lots of money.

Answer (score 0):

The US Census Bureau provides what they call [TIGER files](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/), which might help you out for the US anyway... As far as freely available worldwide data I seriously doubt you're gonna find much, but many governments probably provide something similar to the TIGER files.  Good luck.

Comment: but companies like garmin has a database world wide? you think they are selling it?

Answer (score 0):

I think one good solution would be [Listreet](https://www.listreet.com/)

Samples seems to contain country, region, city, streets and even elevation with longitude and latitude

Prices are fair and the team behind is responsive

Comment: Considering Listreet is a paid service, please provide also an open source service (e.g. OpenStreetMap) or other possible alternatives to Listreet.